# Serialization "ClassName" class, which has property typeof(Encoding) c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, iserializable

I'm sorry if it looks stupid, but I really can`t understand how to serialize my own class which has property:

```
public Encoding EncodingName {get;set;}.
```

Can someone explain what is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: Well, is "Encoding" a serializable class? Have you read about the ISerializable interface?

Comment: What is the problem? `System.Text.Encoding` is marked as `Serializable`.

Comment: When i`m trying to create XML file it throws error "Error when creating document", but if I put [XMLIgnore] before "encodingname" property it works well.

Comment: How about adding another property to your class `public int CodePage
            {
                set { EncodingName = Encoding.GetEncoding(value); }
                get { return EncodingName.CodePage;} }` and mark `EncodingName` with `[XmlIgnore]`

Comment: L4V, thanks for your help. Because of lack of experience and tiredness I missed this option..